# How do you modify the basic CSS of the member registration page?

Tags: registration

Expressionengine 2 makes it extremely easy to bring a potential new member to a site via the registration form with one simple line of code:

```
<a href="{path='member/register'}">sign-up</a>
```

It works, signs up people, etc.  The problem is that there seems to be no template anywhere that populates this page.  Also it generates a ton of CSS.  how can you modify the HTML and or CSS for this page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of the member profile/system templates, but it's not under the Template Designer. Look in the /themes/ folder, under profile_themes/default. That's how you'd find and edit the template files directly on your desktop.

To edit these templates in the EE control panel, choose Design > Member Profile Templates, then go into Default (if that's the theme you're using.) The "CSS Stylesheet" is the CSS for all Default profile template pages. The "Registration Form" is the HTML for the Default profile registration-form template itself.

(This is the same place where you can edit the system error page, the login form, all kinds of goodies. You can even create your own "theme" that's styled very differently from the default one. You just have to remember that you get at them different ways.)

Comment: Okay, found it. In the CP, choose Design > Member Profile Templates. There's the CSS Stylesheet, which controls all styles for the default member templates. Then scroll down that list a bit, you'll see Registration form. There's how to edit the HTML for the registration form.

Comment: I'll warn you: even after you've been using EE for several years...you'll forget where these templates are. (I think almost everyone does, once they edit the profile themes to their satisfaction.) You can create your own totally custom theme by copying that "default" directory, naming it to something else, and then set that theme as your system profile theme.